# The function "query" in Google spreadsheets works for all columns except one

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

In Google spreadsheets I use the following simple formula:

```
=QUERY({'pivot data source'!A:AN},"select * where Col1='2021-08' order by Col2")
```

This works fine so far. However, there is one comment column. It is empty for most rows. Now I added a comment there - it just won't appear in the result of the query formula.

I realized, that it works fine when the comment is a plain number. As soon as there is text, it won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Google Help section for "query"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343):

> In case of mixed data types in a single column, the majority data type determines the data type of the column for query purposes. Minority data types are considered null values.

That means: As long as there are more values with numbers (numeric) than values with text (string), the rows with text will not show up. Even if there are as many numbers as text fields (e.g. one numeric value, one string), Google seems to define the column as numeric and strings don't show up.

To solve this problem, you can try to format the corresponding column in tab "pivot data source" as text (Format > Number > Plain text in the menu).